# Moving django back to sqlite - can't get out of postgres

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-south, heroku-postgres

I set up django with postgres on heroku, and it works great. However, I want to develop locally, and using sqlite is fine for local dev for this project.

I added a local settings file and changed the database settings back to sqlite locally. When I load the site locally, I get the following error:

```
OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Here are my local db settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'wagon_sql.sql3',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

I think I'm just forgetting a step like some version of `syncdb` or something.. but.. not sure. Any ideas on how to get this to work? What other information can I provide to make this more clear?

Thanks!

**Edit**

I think all I'm asking is, after changing my `DATABASE` settings, is there any command I need to run besides restarting the server?

Comment: Are you sure Django is actually using that settings file?

Comment: I print `DATABASES` after I import the file, and it prints out the sqlite info: https://gist.github.com/pjhoberman/7722742. Is that the best way to test?

Comment: First, you should probably use the same database software locally that you do in the cloud.  Postgres is easy to set up on a local machine and I don't think there's any reason not to.  That said, something is obviously not respecting your django config (or Django itself isn't using the one you think it is).

Can you snag a stack trace for the psycopg2 error?

Comment: @MarkRoberts touche. Set up postgres locally, and that works. Good call.